# How to calculate the distance of each pair of one column in r

Tags: r

I tried to calculate the lp norm of all pairs in one column. The answer just not right and I don't know why.

Here is my sample code.

```
 a <- c(23,41,32,58,26,77,45,67,23,78,22,9,20)
lp_norm = function(x, y, p){
 return(sum((abs(x-y))^p)^(1/p))
}
i = 1
while (i <= 13) {
        for(j in i:12){
    lp1 <- lp_norm(a[i],a[j+1],p=1)
    
        }
        i=i+1
        print(lp1)
        
}
}
```

And I have a dataframe with 10 column need to do the same thing. How can I apply this to all column?

Comment: Do you want `outer(a, a, FUN = Vectorize(\(x, y) lp_norm(x, y, p = 1)))` or with `combn` `combn(a, 2, FUN = \(x) lp_norm(x[1], x[2], p = 1))`

Comment: If you need for all 10 columns Loop over the columns and apply i.e. `lapply(yourdat, \(u) combn(u, 2, FUN = \(x) lp_norm(x[1], x[2], p = 1)))`

Comment: Thank you so muuch! These codes are amazing! @akrun

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to calculate this for different combinations of columns in a dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)    

lp_norm <- function(data, x, y, p){
  data |>
    select(v1:= !!sym(x), v2:= !!sym(y))|>
    summarise(lp_norm = sum((abs(v1-v2))^p)^(1/p)) |>
    pull(lp_norm)
}

calc_lp_norm <- function(data, vars, p){
  combn(vars, 2) |>
    t() |>
    `colnames<-`(c("var1", "var2")) |>
    as_tibble()  |>
    mutate(lp_norm = map2_dbl(var1, var2, ~lp_norm(x = .x, y = .y, data = data, p = p)))
}


#few columns
calc_lp_norm(mtcars, c("mpg", "cyl", "hp", "wt"), p = 1)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   var1  var2  lp_norm
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 mpg   cyl     445. 
#> 2 mpg   hp     4051. 
#> 3 mpg   wt      540. 
#> 4 cyl   hp     4496  
#> 5 cyl   wt       95.0
#> 6 hp    wt     4591.

#all columns
calc_lp_norm(mtcars, colnames(mtcars), p = 1)
#> # A tibble: 55 x 3
#>    var1  var2  lp_norm
#>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 mpg   cyl      445.
#>  2 mpg   disp    6740.
#>  3 mpg   hp      4051.
#>  4 mpg   drat     528.
#>  5 mpg   wt       540.
#>  6 mpg   qsec     136.
#>  7 mpg   vs       629.
#>  8 mpg   am       630.
#>  9 mpg   gear     525.
#> 10 mpg   carb     553.
#> # ... with 45 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

We could either use `combn` (only returns pairwise combinations) in `base R`.  Loop over the columns of data.frame 'dat', apply pair combinations of elements (assuming all are unique or else do `combn(unique(u), 2)` and apply the `lp_norm` function

```
lapply(dat, \(u) combn(u, 2, FUN = \(x) lp_norm(x[1], x[2], p = 1)))
```

---

Or if we need the output as a `matrix` (include pairwise combinations of mirror types as well i.e. 1 vs 2 and 2 vs 1 and 1 vs 1)

```
lapply(dat, \(u) outer(u, u, FUN = Vectorize(\(x, y) lp_norm(x, y, p = 1))))
```

But, as this is a distance function, using `outer` will be calculating the same distance twice + distance between the same element